# Conditions for limiting distribution to equal stationary distribution of SDE

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have SDE of the form $$dX_t=a\mathopen{}\left(X_t\right)dt+b\mathopen{}\left(X_t\right)dW_t,$$ where $W$ is Brownian motion. If the stationary distribution of $X$ exist is it equal to the limiting distribution? If not what kind of conditions would I need for them to be the same? I couldn't find any resources on this elsewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: two situations where a distribution is stationary but not approached.

Periodicity: take $a(x)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} x,b=0$. Then $X$ is periodic, any uniform distribution on any given circle is approached, but it is clear that if the initial distribution is a point mass anywhere except the origin, no distribution is approached.

Reducibility: if $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ have simultaneous zeros, then it can happen that there are multiple stationary distributions and so a given stationary distribution might not be approached. For example, $a(x)=-x^2(x-1)(x-2),b(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)$. This will have some distribution which is stationary and concentrated on $[0,1]$ and another concentrated on $[1,2]$. If the initial distribution is, say, uniform on $[0,2]$ then neither of these will be approached because $1$ is an impenetrable wall.

In the finite state space Markov chain context, these are the only things that can go wrong. When the state space becomes infinite, you can definitely have a problem with probability mass escaping "to infinity". If you prohibit that, too (by assuming that $b$ is not too huge and the drift drives you toward the origin if you stray too far from the origin), then you may be able to cook up some theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I kept the question as general as possible in the hope that there was an answer already out there. The $a$ and $b$ I'm working with are much nicer than your examples, in fact they are both linear in $x$ and real valued if that helps.

Comment: @user345722 They are exactly linear, like $dX_t=(aX_t+b)dt+(cX_t+d)dW_t$? In that case there won't be a stationary distribution because the mass will tend to drift away.

Comment: I chose the coefficients so that the process would not drift off. But anyway I was looking to see if the result was true or not since it would help simplify some computations for something I'm doing but I did without it anyway.